# Encontrar todas as instâncias de um padrão em um texto

Tags: python, string, regex, padrão-de-texto

Eu preciso escrever um programa que identifique uma letra minúscula cercada por três letras maiúsculas de cada lado.

Por exemplo:

```
"AEIoSDE" == "o"
```

Eu escrevi o código da seguinte forma:

```
# coding: utf-8
letra = raw_input()

for i in range(1, len(letra) - 7):
    if letra[i].isupper() and not letra[i-1].isupper():
     if letra[i+1].isupper():
      if letra[i+2].isupper():
       if letra[i+3].islower():
        if letra[i+4].isupper():
         if letra[i+5].isupper():
          if letra[i+6].isupper() and not letra[i+7].isupper():
            print letra[i+3]
```

Só que eu preciso fazer isso para uma quantidade massiva de dados, então eu salvei em um arquivo `.txt` e entrei no terminal do Linux e digitei:

```
python criptografia.py < entrada.txt
```

Só que ele me retorna apenas uma letra e não lê as demais strings.

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Por que você colocou `len(letra) - 7`?

Comment: @Orion, porque ele verifica a partir da posição atual. Se não o fizer sairá fora do *vetor* da string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu código funciona normalmente [aqui](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
letra = "AEIoSDEaaAEIoSDEaaAEIoSDEAaaEIoSDEAEIoSDEAEIoSDEAEIoSDEAEIoSDEAEIoSDEAEIoSDEAEIoSDE"
for i in range(0, len(letra) - 7):
      if letra[i].isupper():
           if letra[i+1].isupper() and letra[i+2].isupper():
                 if letra[i+3].islower() and letra[i+4].isupper():
                      #print letra[i+3] + letra[i+4]
                      if letra[i+5].isupper():
                          if letra[i+6].isupper() and not letra[i+7].isupper():
                              print letra[i+3]
```

Saída:

> o
>
> o

Note que você também pode evitar toda essa quantidade de ifs com regex:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

import re
padrao = r'[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}[a-z]'
letra = "AEIoSDEaaAEIoSDEaaAEIoSDEAaaEIoSDEAEIoSDEAEIoSDEAEIoSDEAEIoSDEAEIoSDEAEIoSDEAEIoSDE"
for enc in re.findall(padrao , letra):
    print enc[3]
```

Pode ver esse exemplo rodando [aqui](http://codepad.org/kWUmEl9A)

Comment: Obrigado, cara!!! Eu sou estudante do primeiro período, comecei a estudar Python há pouco mais de três meses, ainda não conheço todas as funções. Foi de grande ajuda a resposta.